# How to evaluate a JS variable represented as a string in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, chromium

I have a csv file that stores the name of JS variables that I would like to read (evaluate) once going to a site. My current implementation, which is based on Puppeteer, iterates on the csv file and stores such variable names in an array named as "variables".

My next step is to iterate on the "variables" array and evaluate each element so I can get its value (like going to the browser console and typing it to retrieve its value). However, either I get an "undefined" value or I just print the name of the variable without evaluating it.

The code looks like this:

```
const variables = [];
//read file and store values in variables)
//...

//open browser and page to evaluate the expression (variable)
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(myTestPage);
  for (const variable of variables) {
    const variableValue = await page.evaluate((x) => {
      return x;
    }, variable);
    console.log(variableValue);
  }
})();
```

Current result is something like:
1.height
2.weight
3.locale
...

But I would expect the value of such variables:
1.1200
2.768
3.en_US
...

Any ideas?

Comment: can you add the website or html code?

Comment: Are the variables/expressions in the `variables` array in form of strings? If yes, you probably want to evaluate them using `eval`. Try replacing `return x;` with `return eval(x);`

Comment: Thank you guys! By using the eval() function I was able to get the variable value :D